# How do I make the jumping smooth?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a platformer game, and I just cant get the jumping to go smooth. with this code:

```
public void tick(){
    if(jumping){
        y -= 8;
        jumping = false;
    }else{

        for(Platform p : game.platforms){
            if(Rect.intersects(getBounds(), p.getBounds()))
                coll = true;            
        }
        if(!coll){
            y += 4;
        }
        coll = false;

    }

}
```

it is to sudden movement. And with this:

```
public void tick(){
    if(jumping){
        y -= 8;

    }else{

        for(Platform p : game.platforms){
            if(Rect.intersects(getBounds(), p.getBounds()))
                coll = true;            
        }
        if(!coll){
            y += 4;
        }else
            jumping = false;
        coll = false;

    }

}
```

It doesn't come down. So, how do I make the jumping smoother?

Comment: It's better off to use a lightweight game engine for such purposes. AndEngine is a good option.

Comment: Im not going to use any engines. It makes the game run slower and bigger(i tried unity, and a app with three objects was 17mb)

Comment: A minimal game in AndEngine could be less than 0.5MB

Comment: You do know this is android? LibGDX isnt alowing input for the android manifest and therefore removes the permission access. Also, LibGDX runs on OpenGL and THAT; that is huge! (in mb)

Comment: Heh.. http://i.imgur.com/ybWKjSM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really would want to use some kind of a physics based approach. At the very least, you should model a velocity in addition to the location.

```
float Velocity=0;

if (isJumping) {
    velocity+=10
    isJumping=false; 
}
y+=velocity;
velocity-=1;
```

You then need to do some check to see if there is an object below you. If so, set your velocity to 0. Feel free to enhance this, but the smoothest approach will result from using a physics based approach.